# Why is the result of my code blank after executing query, on this line $out = $query->result_array();

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is the image of database table.
[image]

I'm new at codeigniter PHP

```
public function ForgotPassword($email)
{ 

    $this->db->select('email');
    $this->db->from('member');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $out = $query->result_array();

    if (count($out) > 0) {
        $email = $out[0]['email'];
        return array('status'=>1, 'email'=>$email); 
    } else {
        return array('status'=>0, 'msg'=>'email not found');
    }
}
```

This is my model function., this line giving me blank result `$out = $query->result_array();` I don't know why, it should give me email address so that i can proceed and send email. I want to send password to user using forgot password function.

```
public function ForgotPassword()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $findemail = $this->MY_model->ForgotPassword($email);

    if ($findemail['status'] == 1) {
        $this->MY_model->sendpassword($findemail);
    } else {
        echo " $email not found, enter correct email id";
    }
}
```

And this is my controller function. Here I'm getting blank value of  `$findemail`. I don't know why.

```
public function sendpassword($data)
{
    $email = $data['email'];

    $query1=$this->db->query("SELECT * from member where email = '".$email."' ");
    $row=$query1->result_array();
    if ($query1->num_rows() > 0) {
        $passwordplain = "";
        $passwordplain  = rand(10000000,99999999);
        $newpass['password'] = md5($passwordplain);
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->update('member', $newpass);
        $mail_message='Dear '.$row[0]['username'].','. "\r\n";
        $mail_message.=' Your <b>Password</b> is 
                       <b>'.$passwordplain.'</b>'."\r\n";

        require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php';
        require 'class.phpmailer.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsSendmail();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $subject = 'Testing Email';
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->IsMail();
        $mail->From = 'vishal@gmail.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'admin';
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $mail_message;
        $mail->Send();
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Failed to send password";
        } else {
            echo "Password sent ! check your mail";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Email not found!!!!";
    }
}
```

**And also upper model function , it's not sending email. I'm using phpmailer to sending email. Please help.**

Comment: public function ForgotPassword(){}; Why don't you pass this function $email as parameter ?

Comment: @vieroli it does not work, showing the blank array

Comment: The first function ForgotPassword($email) is working ? But the second function ForgotPassword() doesn't ?

Comment: in first function ForgotPassword($email) showing blank array at this line $out = $query->result_array(); i have checked using echo $this->db->last_query(); die(); i dont know why?

Comment: So try to check at your sql query

Comment: yes i checked its giving blank array

Comment: So either your query is wrong, or data from your db is not reached

Comment: that is what i'm not figure out as i'm new in php @vieroli

Comment: Formatted code, removed unnecessary quotation blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model name is 'MY_model' then write construct function in your controller file and load the model into it as shown below.

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('my_model');
    }
```

And modify your ForgotPassword function of controller as below.

```
public function ForgotPassword()
{
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$findemail = $this->my_model->ForgotPassword($email);

if ($findemail['status'] == 1) {
    $this->my_model->sendpassword($findemail);
} else {
    echo " $email not found, enter correct email id";

}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply but it is still giving blank array, in model function ForgotPassword($email) at line $out = $query->result_array();

Comment: Can you please try printing $email and $out in your model's `ForgotPassword` function and exit after it?

Comment: i'm getting this result SELECT `email` FROM `member` WHERE `email` = 'vishal.@gmail.com' when i wrote this  echo $this->db->last_query(); die(); below this line $query=$this->db->get();                                                             and when i wrote this line print_r($out); die(); below this line $out = $query->result_array(); im getting this Array ()

Comment: Can you please send me screenshot of your records in member table of your database?

Comment: see i have uploaded image above link at the top

Comment: @VishalPoriya...The email id you are posting is not matching with any of the record of your member table.So its returning empty array.

Comment: no, i have entered the same email id which i mentioned in table while running but still it's showing me empty array

Comment: @VishalPoriya...Honestly i ca see only 7 records in your screenshot and none of the record matches with the query you printed.

Comment: @VishalPoriya...Can you please fire `SELECT email FROM member WHERE email = 'vishal.@gmail.com' ` this query into your phpmyadmin and paste the result here?

Comment: SELECT email FROM member WHERE email = 'vishal.poriya404@gail.com' im getting this result Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0010 seconds.)

Comment: work for me . but now another problem arise is, i'm not able to receive mail, im send on my own email id..

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function that checks if email exists in db. It is named CheckUser().
Then in ForgotPassword() you call CheckUser() ($email must be given as argument).

```
<?php
    public function CheckUser($email)
    {
        $response = $bdd->prepare('SELECT email FROM member WHERE email = :email');
        $response->execute([
          "email" => $$email
        ]);
        $data = $response->fetchAll();

        return $data[0];
    }

    public function ForgotPassword($email)
    {
        // here you call our new function
```

** UDPATE BELOW CALLING OF CHECKUSER FUNCTION **

```
        $out = $this->CheckUser($email);

        // sizeof will return the lenght of the returned data from our CheckUser() function
        if (sizeof($out) > 0){
            $email = $out[0]['email'];
            return array('status'=>1, 'email'=>$email); 
        }
        else {
            return array('status'=>0, 'msg'=>'email not found');
        }

    }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function CheckUser() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\models\MY_model.php on line 19